# PHP - imagecreatetruecolor - allowed memory size of exhausted

Tags: php, io

I need to combine these images into one. For that I do the following:

1. Create an blank image with right dimensions

   `$full_image = imagecreate($full_width, $full_height);`
2. Copy png images one by one onto the blank image

   `imagecopy($full_image, $src, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $src_width, $src_height`)

However, some images get really big  ex: `imagecreatetruecolor(8832, 3955);`  and I get `Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8832 bytes)`

I wonder if there is a way to put image together, without storing the entire image in memory. Maybe write image data to disk at certain intervals while generating image.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly: When you're finished with a resource or a large array etc, use unset($resource); to mark it as being "ready" for garbage collection.

Secondly, image processing is pretty intensive. You could look into using something like [Gearman](http://gearman.org/), which basically allows you to farm out intensive processes to a queue.

Thirdly, you could also try this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');
```